# Accessing the SharePoint list in custom webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, jquery-ajax

I am creating the webpart in my app for SharePoint 2013 and office 365. I have tried to accessing the SharePoint list in my webpart using ajax request like this,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: siteURL + "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/" + listName,
    error: function (evt) {
        alert("Error");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // Processing the data.
    }
});
```

It throws cross domain accessing error message. If i add a **'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'** headers to access the cross domain then it shows **"preflight is invalid redirect error"** message. How to get the sharepoint list items in custom webpart.

Comment: Shows us the domain names of your siteUrl AND the location where you webPart is running (or do you mean your are creating an APP?)

Comment: Yes, i am creating the app. My domain name is looks like this, "https://company-name.sharepoint.com" and webpart is "https://company-name-505e4a7d8b6f5f.sharepoint.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App runs in a different Domain, so you can't just call another Domain (the HostWeb)

You have to execute through SharePoint's own SP.RequestExecutor

See all SO posts:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=RequestExecutor